# Is there a way to find the GCP VM startup script's return code

Tags: linux, unix, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have startup scripts associates with the Compute Engine VMs. I would like to know if there is a way to find out the return code of these startup scripts. I currently tail the serial port logs to check the return code. But, is there any other place where i can look this up?

```
gcloud compute instances tail-serial-port-output compute-vm-1 \
    --project=gcp-project-hw1 --zone=us-central1-a | egrep "Return code "
```

Comment: This question looks off-topic here as written. Why not check the return code using something like systemd's `systemctl`?

Comment: curious about why you might feel that this is off-topic..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return code is within the VM, using the serial port simply provides you the feedback from the VM and allows you to view this information without connecting to the instance. The serial port is the only way to look for the response code without directly accessing the VM